# Fetch only values from neo4j database

Tags: reactjs, neo4j

I am trying to fetch some data from my neo4j database and show in a list for auto suggestion in reactjs application. I have following codes to fetch the data.

```
  let result = null; 
    
    try {
      result = await session.run(
        'MATCH (n:Person) RETURN properties(n)',
        
      )} finally {
      await session.close()
    }
    await driver.close()
```

Here the Person nodes have different properties, i.e. all the Person nodes do not have same properties. some have editor name, others have author name. What i want to do is fetching only values without keys and assigning them in an array.  here

```
'MATCH (n:Person) RETURN properties(n)'
```

returns

```
{
  "myName": "myname 1",
  "hisName": "myname 2"
}
{
  "herName": "myname 3",
  "theirName": "myname 4"
}
```

And `'MATCH (n:Person) RETURN keys(n)'` returns

```
["myName"]
["hisName"]
["herName"]
["theirName"]
```

But i want to fetch only values [myname 1, myname 2, myname 3, myname 4]

Could you please tell me how to fetch only values ?
Also how to keep those values in an array ?

Comment: Check if that property key (myName) exists then do "collect" to put them in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to get all values for the key myName in Person class.

1. Check if the node has this property using EXISTS
2. Put the values in an array using "COLLECT".

   ```
    MATCH (n:Person) 
    WHERE EXISTS(n.myName) 
    RETURN collect(distinct n.myName)
   ```

Sample result:

["Zhen", "Praveena", "Michael", "Arya", "Karin", "Adam", "John", "mary", "jack", "david", "tom"]

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
MATCH(n:Person)
RETURN apoc.coll.flatten(COLLECT(EXTRACT(key IN keys(n) | n[key])))
```

p.s. Sorry, EXTRACT() has been deprecated. Below is better.

```
MATCH(n:Shima)
RETURN apoc.coll.flatten(COLLECT([key IN keys(n) | n[key]]))
```